# Nginx - Client real IP in header field

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm using Nginx for load balancing, but my web app sometimes requires the real IP of the user.

Therefore in the client request header I'd like to be able to get the user's real IP address, not just the load balancer's IP address.

I added the following part to my location block:

```
            set_real_ip_from  172.3.4.5;    #address of my load balancer 
            real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
            real_ip_recursive on;
```

But it seems like the X-Forwarded-For field is not being send at all for that IP. I can't see it in Wireshark/Chrome Dev Tools/etc.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "nginx -v" tells me "nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)". It has not been installed with additional modules as far as I know. Is it possible to achieve my request without additional modules?

Comment: I see, sorry! It says "--with-http_realip_module" using nginx -V

Comment: Thanks, I edited the topic to be more specific after your advice.

Comment: [`set_real_ip_from`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#set_real_ip_from) should be the IP address(es) of your downstream load balancer.